# Angularjs filtering multilevel JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using angular filter for writing items from JSON to table. It works well in first level, but then I have taxonomies in JSON, which I am writing down by inner loop, but I am not able to apply filter on this values (only fulltext works).

I've tried things like `search.taxs.bank.name` (it's path to value) or path with the identificator of inner loop, but nothing works. `OrderBy` is the same case (works only on first level).

Comment: Could you reveal part of that JSON? we could write a customized filter

Comment: Yep, Maybe, you could share with us a gist file for example.

Comment: It can look like this (it's simplify), there can be more taxonomies:
`[ { 
 "ID" : 21 , 
 "post_title" : "Air Bank" , 
 "post_excerpt" : "" , 
 "info_maximalni_vyber" : "0" , 
 "prispevek_unicef" : "0" , 
 "taxs" : { 
  "bank" : [ 
  { 
   "term_id" : 4 , 
   "name" : "Air Bank" , 
   "slug" : "air-bank" , 
   "term_group" : 0 , 
   "term_taxonomy_id" : 4 , 
   "taxonomy" : "bank" , 
   "description" : "" , 
   "parent" : 0 , 
   "count" : 1 , 
   "filter" : "raw"
  }
  ]
 }
}] `